# ajax callback function is not called

Tags: 8, ajax

- I'm testing ajax callback functionality in drupal 8
- I have a custom module which is a simple form
- Added an ajax callback to submit button

### Code:

```
namespace Drupal\ajax_form_submit\Form;
    
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;

/**
 * Implementing a ajax form.
 */
class AjaxSubmitDemo extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'ajax_submit_demo';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['message'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="result_message"></div>',
    ];

    $form['number_1'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Number 1'),
    ];

    $form['number_2'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Number 2'),
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::setMessage',
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Setting the message in our form.
   */
  public function setMessage(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(
      new HtmlCommand(
        '.result_message',
        '<div class="my_top_message">' . t('The results is @result', ['@result' => ($form_state->getValue('number_1') + $form_state->getValue('number_2'))]) . '</div>'
      )
    );
    return $response;
  }

  /**
   * Submitting the form.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

}
```

- Clicking on submit reloads the whole page rather than giving an ajax response
- Provided complete path of function in callback but still the same
- Attached the screenshot showing the error messages from the console pointing
  to the syntax error in jquery.min.js under /core/assets/vendor
- Using [sales zymphonies theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/sales_zymphonies_theme).
- When I change the theme to Bartik, everything works fine.
- Trying to understand what might be the problem from the theme that might be messing with the ajax callback.
- Raised the issue on the project page as well, but trying to understand how an ajax callback here is dependent on the theme's javascript/jquery to call the callback function
- Any suggestion or guidance towards possible reasons is appreciated

[image]

Comment: The submit button executes a normal form submit, because the ajax onclick event is attached after the document is loaded and this is not possible when js is not working.

Comment: Does this mean the js of this specific theme is not working? Because everything works fine as expected when its Bartik theme. Is there a possible workaround to have a button perform an ajax callback?

Comment: To be more specific, you need to make sure that `Drupal.behaviors.AJAX` in `ajax.js` is executed on a page load.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll look into what Drupal.behaviors is and try to implement it appropriately to let the ajax callback be executed on page load

Comment: @4k4 Thank You for your timely help on this. I included the below:
'#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'return (false);'),
hoping this would prevent the form submission and allow the ajax callback 

Interestingly, I was hoping to include this within $form['action'] but including it within '#ajax' seemed to work

Probably, making a button and its action as invalid and allowing the ajax callback.
Seems like a workaround rather than a solution, even if it works.

Comment: The appropriate solution should be to make sure that the ajax callback takes preference over the button submission as mentioned by 4k4

@4k4 is there a way that I can accept your comment as an answer to this?